# Display table with s:iterator in Struts 2

Tags: java, html, struts2, struts

I want to jsp page with html code

```
<table>
    <s:iterator >
        <tr>
            <td>My love</td>
            <td><s:submit name="btnPlay" value="Play"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>My life</td>
            <td><s:submit name="btnPlay" value="Play"/></td>
        </tr>
    </s:iterator>
</table>
```

I want to display as follow:

[image]

but it's display as:

[image]

Can you help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set `theme` attribute to `simple` in your `<s:submit>` tag

```
<s:submit name="btnPlay" value="Play" theme="simple"/>
```